# Custom JSONEncoder for requests.post

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm writing wrapper for REST API and use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module.

Method `.json()` of [Response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) object transfers `**kwargs` to `json.loads()` function, so I can easily use custom JSON decoder and, i. e. transparently convert UNIX epoch timestamps to datetime.datetime objects.

Is there any way to use custom JSON encoder with [Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Request) object? Seems I can only use parameter json, but can't find how to use custom JSON encoder with it.

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to do? [This question looks very XY to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This is probably relevant: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2755.

Comment: alecxe, seems that's the answer for my question, thank you. Could you make it a separate answer?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Extracting the answer from the [link provided by alecxe](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2755), using a custom encoder and the json parameter is not supported. It's recommended you just construct the post manually.

```
r = requests.post('http://foo.bar',
              data=json.dumps(some_data, cls=CustomJSONEncoder),
              headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, small note, when using `json=...`, requests adds a `content-type` value of `application/json`, which some servers expect. When calling requests with your own-encoded JSON payload, you may have to add `headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}` (again, depending if the server you're interacting with cares about this or not)